# ¿Se puede llamar a una función sin el decorador? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, decoradores

Espero que me puedan ayudar con un poco de teoría.

He conocido a la función decorador, entendiendo que añade funcionalidad a otra función. Me pregunto, si yo tengo una función original y la decoro, *¿ya no puedo llamar a la función original sin las funcionalidades del decorador?*

Me explico, si yo tengo una función que suma y le añado un decorador que adicional a la suma imprime un mensaje. *¿Ya no podre llamar solo a la función suma?* Buscando información, he visto que explican su uso y sus ventajas, pero no mencionan si se puede o si no hacer eso de manera explicita.

```
def decorador(funcion):
    def nueva(*args):
        print("Estamos sumando")
        funcion(*args)
        print("Terminamos de sumar")
    return nueva


@decorador
def suma(num1, num2, num3):
    return print(num1 + num2 + num3)

suma(4,7,2)
```

Gracias. Saludos.

Comment: Editada la entrada compañeros!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí, hay varias formas de conseguirlo:

## 1. Crear un atributo en el propio decorador

Consiste en crear un atributo en el propio decorador, que pueda llamar directamente a la función original que tú le pasas. Tu ejemplo quedaría así

```
def decorador(funcion):
    def nueva(*args):
        print("Estamos sumando")
        funcion(*args)
        print("Terminamos de sumar")
    nueva._original = funcion     # Esta es la parte que añadimos
    return nueva


@decorador
def suma(num1, num2, num3):
    return print(num1 + num2 + num3)

suma(4,7,2)
#Ahora llamamos al atributo de suma que nos pasa la función original y le damos los valores.
print(suma._original(4,7,2))
```

## 2. Si usas wrap

En este caso, si usas la función `wraps` de `functools` para crear decoradores, el funcionamiento es basicamente el mismo. llamamos mediante el método especial `__wrapped__` a la función original.

```
from functools import wraps

def decorador(funcion):
    @wraps(funcion)
    def nueva(*args):
        print("Estamos sumando")
        funcion(*args)
        print("Terminamos de sumar")
    return nueva


@decorador
def suma(num1, num2, num3):
    return print(num1 + num2 + num3)

print(suma(4,7,2))
print(suma.__wrapped__(4,7,2))
```

## 3. Usar el paquete undecorated

Esta librería se puede instalar con `pip install undecorated` y basicamente lo que hace es convertir nuestra función decorada en la original.

```
from undecorated import undecorated

def decorador(funcion):
    def nueva(*args):
        print("Estamos sumando")
        funcion(*args)
        print("Terminamos de sumar")
    return nueva


@decorador
def suma(num1, num2, num3):
    return print(num1 + num2 + num3)

suma = undecorated(suma)
print(suma(4,7,2))
```

Como ves todos los métodos son muy sencillos y fáciles de usar!

Answer (score 4):

> ¿ya no puedo llamar a la función original sin las funcionalidades del decorador?

De manera natural **no**, un decorador no es más que una manera *linda* de definir una función que devuelve a otra función.

```
def debug(func):
    def decorate(a,b,c):
        print(f"El resultado de la función es {func(a,b,c)}")

    return decorate

@debug
def func(a,b,c):
    return a * b * c
```

En este fragmento de código se definen dos funciones, `debug()` y `func()`. Como verás, en `debug()` se define y retorna otra función llamada `decorate()`. Si llamamos `func(1,2,3)`, vamos a obtener esto

```
El resultado de la función es 6
```

Por la tanto se puede decir que **la definición de `func()` cambió.** Por lo tanto la vieja `func()` ya no existe. Al decorar la función, se pierde la definición original de la función.

> ¿Ya no podre llamar solo a la función suma?

Claro que puedes, simplemente **no decores la función.**

```
def foo(bar):
    print(f"El resultado de la función es {bar}")

def bar(a,b,c):
    return a * b * c

bar_decorated = foo(bar(4,5,6))
```

En este otro fragmento de código, se define `foo()`, `bar()` y `bar_decorated`.

- La función `foo()` recibe como argumento una función y muestra un texto en pantalla con el resultado de dicha función
- La función `bar()` recibe tres argumentos numéricos y devuelve el resultado de multiplicar dichos argumentos entre si.
- bar_decorated también es una función, **sin argumentos.** Esta se define como la ejecución de `foo()` con `bar()` y tres números (lastimosamente fijos) como argumentos.

Si invocas `bar_decorated` (importante sin paréntesis), obtienes

```
El resultado de la función es 120
```

### ¿Qué pasa si quiero que mi función decorada reciba argumentos?

Puedes definir una función normal (que si reciba argumentos) y retornar la función decorada.

```
def bar_decorated(a,b,c):
    return foo(bar(a,b,c))
```

Luego, puedes llamarla como una función cualquiera. Al llamarla con `bar_decorated(7,8,9)` obtendrías

```
El resultado de la función es 504
```

Obviamente luego puedes llamar a `bar()` individualmente. Por ejemplo, un `print(bar(3,6,9))` mostraría `162`.

> entendiendo que añade funcionalidad a otra función

Como ya has visto, un decorador no es la gran cosa. No es más que una manera *bonita* de hacer que una función retorne a otra, puedes darle esa funcionalidad tu mismo. A esto también se le conoce como [azúcar sintáctico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Az%C3%BAcar_sint%C3%A1ctico).

Entonces, respondiendo a tu pregunta:

> ¿Se puede llamar a una función sin el decorador?

No, una vez decorada la función no se puede. Sin embargo es posible cumplir la misma función de un decorador sin tener que reescribir la función.

Espero haberte ayudado ;)

Answer (score 2):

Las dos respuestas anteriores son excelentes, sobre todo la de @rubiales-alberto . Esta respuesta tiene bastante de *hackeo* del funcionamiento de python.

Cuando se *decora* una función se crea una *clausura* alrededor de ella. Esta clausura se puede acceder a través de las propiedades de la función decorada.

Así por ejemplo, para acceder a la función original:

```py
suma_original = suma.__closure__[0].cell_contents

suma_original(4,7,2)
```

Con `__closure__` se accede a la clausura, de la que pillamos la primera *celda* que se corresponde con la función original (es el primero y único argumento que recibe).

El problema aquí es que el concepto de *celda* de una clausura no está documentado y podría depender de cómo hagan las clausuras las distintas implementaciones de python.

Un modo más seguro sería usando el módulo [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/inspect.html). A través de este módulo podemos inspeccionar la clausura:

```py
import inspect

closure = inspect.getclosurevars(suma)
print(closure.nonlocals)
```

Resultado:

```
{'funcion': <function suma at 0x00000000023D7670>}
```

Como vemos, con `nonlocals` obtenemos los argumentos que ha recibido el decorador que es lo que nos sirve en este caso para recuperar la función original:

```py
suma_original = list(closure.nonlocals.values())[0]
```

Pero hay que tener cuidado, no siempre tenemos decoradores tan simples. Por ejemplo, podríamos definir uno parametrizado:

```py
def decora(msg):
    def decorador(func):
        def newfunction(*args):
            msg()
            func(*args)
        return newfunction
    return decorador

def msg():
    print("Mensaje")


@decora(msg)
def suma(a,b,c):
    print(a+b+c)
```

Si hacemos una inspección:

```py
import inspect

closure = inspect.getclosurevars(suma)
print(closure.nonlocals)
```

Resultado:

```
{'func': <function suma at 0x0000000003233CA0>, 'msg': <function msg at 0x00000000023D7790>}
```

Como vemos, la clausura tiene dos argumentos que se corresponden con las dos *"celdas"* de la clausura. Sin mirar detenidamente el código no se tiene la garantía de cuál de los dos es la función original `suma`.

Comment: Gracias @ChemaCortes gran aporte con tu respuesta también :)